# Python: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

My code is shown as follows, which is used to search for closed cells

```
    best_i += h.i_offset; best_i = keep_in_range(best_i, 0, b.nni-1)
    best_j += h.j_offset; best_j = keep_in_range(best_j, 0, b.nnj-1)
    best_k += h.k_offset; best_k = keep_in_range(best_k, 0, b.nnk-1)
    Block.blockList[best_block].hcell_list.append( (best_i, best_j, best_k) )
```

However, there is an error

```
Block.blockList[best_block].hcell_list.append( (best_i, best_j, best_k) )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What module are you using, what are you trying to do, what are the variables, how are they declared, please clarify. This question is too unclear.

Comment: Why? Because `Block.blockList[best_block].hcell_list` is `None`.

Comment: As you are trying to use append on a None type object, it obviously throws an error. To handle the situation, you make sure that Block.blockList[best_block].hcell_list is not None.

Answer (score 0):

If `Block.blockList[best_block].hcell_list` is None then using a list method on it will not work. You need to figure out why it has a `None` value *then* you can `append` values to the list, you cannot append anything to a `None`.

This is about all I can say will the lack of information you gave, but basically just figure out where you declare `Block.blockList[best_block].hcell_list` as `None` change it to a list and it should work.

If you are are using a library try to open it up and figure out how to use it and check what type of value it should have.

Answer (score 0):

`Block.blockList[best_block].hcell_list` should not be None if you are going to call `append` method.
append is a method of list data type.
Please make sure into your code that you are passing `Block.blockList[best_block].hcell_list` is  list.